# Simple CIFilter Passthru with CGImage conversion returns black pixels

Tags: ios, cifilter

The following code:

```
let skView = SKView()
let scene = SKScene()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    self.skView.presentScene(self.scene)
    self.scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.view.addSubview(skView)
    self.scene.shouldEnableEffects = true

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "NAME_THAT_PIC")
    sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 300, y: 400)

    let effectNode = SKEffectNode()
    effectNode.filter = MyFilter()
    effectNode.addChild(sprite)
```

will call this custom filter that does nothing but create a CGImage from a CIImage, correctly invoking `context.createCGImage()` as reported by many people (CIImages are not pixel buffered.)

`MyFilter` is reduced to a simple repro test:

```
class MyFilter: CIFilter {

    var inputImage: CIImage?

    var inputImageRect: CGRect? {
        guard let image = self.inputImage else {
            return nil
        }
        return image.extent
    }

    public override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override open var outputImage: CIImage? {

        guard let inputImage = self.inputImage else {
            return nil
        }

        let context = CIContext(options:nil)
        let cgImage = context.createCGImage(inputImage, from: inputImageRect!)

        // ... DO SOMETHING WITH CGIMAGE DATA ...

        return CIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
    }
}
```

If I replace `MyFilter()` by another built-in filter, it works and will show the altered image so the viewcontroller code works. If instead, I return `inputImage` directly from the filter output call, it works and the image passed in will display.

When I dump the CGImage, the dimensions of the image are correct but every pixels are set to black.

I tried creating a UIImage using `UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)` but the same happens.

What is causing pixels not to be loaded in the cgImage I generated from the inputImage?

Comment: I don't work with SpriteKit, but I'm seeing two things with `MyFilter` that concern me. (1) Why are you creating a `CIContext` every single time you call `outputImage`? This won't impact the result, but it *will* impact performance. (2) Why are you making `outputImage` optional? Your code calling for it will never fail if it's nil.

Comment: As for the optional, it's an override and that's how Apple defines it. I have to return what the superclass expects in its signature (`open var outputImage: CIImage? { get }`). As for the context, it's a code sample. I wrote it to be concise. I can always move the context creation later when things finally work.

Comment: I checked every single one of my subclassed `CIFIlters` (about 40 in one project) and none of them have an optional return for the `outputImage` override. Some have been defined as a "bare" CIImage, some as a "forced-unwrapped" one (and yes, in testing I've had execution errors for the nil return. I'm not necessarily saying that *this* is the issue, but a "black image" certainly is a possible behavior for displaying a `nil` return.